# Is reload cancelling faster?

Tags: overwatch

Today I learned that, for all heroes with limited ammunition, they can reload cancel their weapons with a melee attack.

What I'm curious about is, does it really save time? Is it really a "cancel"?  I'll give an example.

With Reaper's shotguns, if he presses reload, the ammo indicator on the bottom right will instantly refresh to 8/8, but it will still play the "drop gun, pull new ones out of thin air" animation.   If I melee after pressing reload, it will allow me to fire as soon as the melee animation takes place.

However, what I've seen is that if I press melee immediately after I press reload, there seems to be a delay as to when I can fire the shotguns. If I wait just a half-second later to press melee, then I can fire almost immediately.  Because of this delay, I'm wondering if reload cancelling really does save time, or is the reload time set, regardless of cancelling?

Comment: Just curious, what happens when you try to "reload cancel" with a character with no "limited ammunition" (can't test it right now)

Comment: Well, you can't reload cancel for infinite ammo characters because, like their name implies, they have infinite ammo. Limited ammo means they have a magazine or a clip, like Reaper's Shotguns, S76's Pulse Rifle, Genji's Shuriken, etc.  Infinite meaning weapons like Hanzo's Storm Bow, D.va's Particle Cannons. Basically, infinite = no reload necessary

Comment: Ah for some reason, I thought you meant like "not a lot of ammo" like Reaper.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not. After a reload cancel there is a delay, which is equal to the time required to reload without canceling the animation. I suppose that reload animations were made to fit the reload time, not the other way around.
Here are two GIFs,which demonstrate that (by reddit user - **daddatv**):

[At full speed](https://i.imgur.com/UIyP9Ot.mp4)

[Frame by frame](https://i.imgur.com/JDXXvsr.mp4)

Comment: Please note that [Gfycat](https://gfycat.com) will shut down on Sept. 1, 2023. This affects the media you included in your post since they were uploaded to Gfycat. I recommend that you edit your post and reupload the Gfycat media through SE Imgur to avoid losing them. You might need to edit the media to make it ≤ 2 MiB, which is the maximum file size allowed by SE Imgur. See [this meta post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16826/4797) for more info.

Comment: The links have been updated to use Imgur.

Comment: That's good to know. By the way, were those uploaded via a logged-in account on Imgur? I'm asking because a 2023-05-15 [change in Imgur’s TOS could cause the loss of those media](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16762/4797) if they weren't uploaded using a logged-in account. (Note that this doesn't apply to SE Imgur.)

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing with McCree and Soldier 76 and compared the times in a video so feel free to check it out!

Comment: Thanks for posting the video, but would you mind adding a short description of your findings? It's viewed as polite for people who might not be able to watch the video :)

Answer (score 1):

Frame perfectly, I think so.

In my [testing with Mei](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-nCbtsQS_w#t=7m18), it's equal, but I also use a timing that's more consistent I think, rather than perfect. My projectiles start at an angle though.

[As DGarvanski referenced](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/267398/46216), [/u/daddatv](https://www.reddit.com/user/daddatv) found out [Reaper can shoot two frames faster by interrupting reload with melee](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/4i9ril/reaper_reload_animation_cancel/d2wmaqd).